# How to show popup window if users does not accepts all permission in Android Marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am following the example of `Pokemon Go` app to show a window message likes

> You need to [Location, Camera,...] access to use this application. Please allow access in this application [Setting]. Click [Cancel] to exit from this application

When I click the Setting, the application will go to Setting window of this application and I can accept all Permissions.

The Setting window can access by using the code

```
public void gotoSetting(){
  final Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
  i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
  i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
  startActivity(i);
}
```

There are my permisions which are stored in a String array

```
 String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
 Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
 Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
 Manifest.permission.CAMERA}
```

I used this code to check if all permission are checked, otherwise it returns false

```
public static boolean hasAllPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, I got an issue that event I did not check all permissions, but the  application did not go to Setting again. In additions, I can show an window message to notify if the user did not check all permission. Finally, This is my code

```
private AlertDialog buildNotificationServiceAlertDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Pemissions Setting");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("You need to [Location, Camera,...] access to use this application. Please allow access in this application [Setting]. Click [Cancel] to exit from this application");
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Setting",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    gotoSetting();
                }
            });
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // If you choose to not enable the notification listener
                    // the app. will not work as expected
                }
            });
    return(alertDialogBuilder.create());
}
```

In onCreate I have

```
    private AlertDialog enableNotificationListenerAlertDialog;
    if(!hasAllPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        enableNotificationListenerAlertDialog = buildNotificationServiceAlertDialog();
        enableNotificationListenerAlertDialog.show();
    }
```

Update: **Solved:**. I was missing to call the `hasAllPermissions` in the `onResume()` function. Finally, my solution is

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(hasAllPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)==false){
        enableNotificationListenerAlertDialog = buildNotificationServiceAlertDialog();
        enableNotificationListenerAlertDialog.show();
    }
```

}

Comment: Please go through this link,
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/runtime-permission-aman-shekhar

Comment: I do not want to use runtime permission. My expected result as PokeMapGo app

Comment: what is `voide` in `public voide gotoSetting()` ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it. Let check it again.

Comment: did u make any console logs to catch the code run like `Log.e("here", "here this code run")`, try and see where the code is making error /

Comment: I got it. The missing is that I did not call the hasAllPermissions function in onResume. It need to call at this function

Answer (score 0):

I read your question carefully and i notice one mistake in your first line of code.As your code start with "public voide gotoSetting()",The mistake is in the keyword spelling.By correcting, it can be written as "public void gotoSetting()".

I hope this will help you.